# Creating a dynamical array of objects in the constructor of a different class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor

I have a headache. Is the following code snippet right? I would like to create an array of 19 B objects, which contains another array of X A objects. (X is variable, I mean that the As array could vary in length between the B objects)

Later on I would like to say something like `B_obj[i].As[j].number = 0;` 
(i = [0-18], j = [0 - depends on the object])

Example:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A();

    private:
        char *arena;
        size_t size;
        int number;
};

A::A()
{
    size = 5;

    arena= (char *) malloc (size);

   ... some code ...
}

class B
{
    private:
        int counter;
        A* As;

    public:
        B();
};

B::B()
{
    counter = getMyNumber(); /* getMyNumber returns an individual ID */
    As= (A*) malloc(counter * sizeof(A)));
}

B B_obj[19];
```

Is the memory correct allocated? Everything have to be setup, I am not allowed to alloc extra memory later on.

Comment: Whenever you think "dynamic array", your next thought should be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: 1. don't use `malloc` in C++ (except in certain advanced cases) 2. don't use raw arrays (prefer `std::vector`)

Comment: And *never* use `malloc` to allocate memory in C++. While it works to allocate memory, it doesn't *construct* the objects. I.e. in your case the `A` constructor will never be called. Using `std::vector` of course solves both the allocation and construction problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for you advices. I choosed malloc, because I have to use a similar function, that only retruns a pointer to some memory. I will try to use the vector. Can you please give me a hint, on how I could call the constructor of A? What do I have to change?

Comment: That's one of the beauties of C++. you don't call the constructor. The constructor is called for you if you allocate statically or with `new`.

Comment: So you mean you want to create an array of 19 objects of type *B*, and each object has, as a field of the class, an array of a variable number of *A* objects?

Comment: @stackptr Correct, That is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to create an array of 19 B objects, which contains another array of X A objects.

```
class B {
    std::vector<A> x;
public:
    // your public interface here
};

B arr[19];
```

The solution becomes very simple when you use good RAII solutions like `std::vector`, because it does the memory management for you. Memory is allocated automatically, and you can use [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to allocate a certain number of `A` objects in the vector.